# how to get textbox value from one user control to other in c#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, user-controls, textbox

I have two user control's . In the first user control(**Class**) i have one `textbox`.

Now in my second user control (**Test**), i want to get the value of that `textbox`.

in my page, when user enter a value in `texbox` of the first `usercontrol`, how can i get this in the hidden field of the second `usercontrol`

How can I do this??

I have these properties in my usercontrols

**Class** User Control

```
public string Class_ClientId
        {
            get { return txtClass.ClientID; }
        }
public string Class_Text
        {
            get { return Class; }
            set
            {
                if (value != Class)
                {
                    Class = value;
                    txtClass.Text = Class;
                }
            }
        }
```

**Test** user control

```
public string KMAT_Text
        {
            get { return KMATName; }
            set
            {
                if (value != KMATName)
                {
                    KMATName = value;
                    txtKmat.Text = KMATName;
                }
            }
        }
 public string Class
        {
            get { return _hdnClass; }
            set
            {
                if (value!= _hdnClass)
                {
                    _hdnClass = value;
                    hdnClass.Value = _hdnClass;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: When do you want the copying to happen? On postback?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363899/passing-values-between-web-user-controls

Comment: @SystemDown I am using an Jquery autofill on textbox. Now in my page, i want when user select a value from autofil, it will also copied to the hidden value(Class) of the second usercontrol

Answer (score 2):

There are a variety of ways to do this.  The easiest to implement would be to define a change event on the first user control:

```
public event EventHandler SomethingChanged;

protected void OnSomethingChanged(EventArgs e)
{
   if (SomethingChanged != null)
     SomethingChanged(this, e);
}

public string Class_Text
        {
            get { return Class; }
            set
            {
                if (value != Class)
                {
                    Class = value;
                    txtClass.Text = Class;

                    this.OnSomethingChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
                }
            }
        }
```

Have the page listen for it, and have the page pass the value to the second user control.

Comment: A user control sits within a page.  The first user control can add an event.  The page listens for that event to be fired.  When the page receives that the event was fired, the page does an assignment to your class property on the second control: `uc2.Class = uc1.Class_Text;`